# Keep track of IPs on website

Tags: php, sql, ip, unique

I want to keep track of all unique users that view a certain website. I could do this by making a log-in system, but that's not a viable solution for my wishes. I would like to get the IP of someone to keep track of everything that person has done (it is a system where people have to judge sentence quality and they must preferably only get a certain sentence once).

I've seen this solution:
`echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];`

How useful/recommended is this for my wishes? Any recommendations? I would have an SQL-table containing with such an IP address as primary key to store the judgements that have been made.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you really need your own login system for that, there's no alternative. IP does not=person. 1 person can use many IP's and MANY people can be 1 IP

Comment: True. Perhaps I should rephrase; I want to restrict it on systemlevel; i.e. one person may use different systems without having to be treated as the same person; making the assumption that most people will only be using the website on one system. It need not be true; it's not THAT important. People just shouldn't come across the same sentences <i>TOO MUCH</i>. Thanks though :)

Comment: http is stateless, either implement a login system or don't bother with this at all

Comment: Thank you! I have little experience with sessions yet.

Answer (score 0):

As Dagon says, an IP address will inevitably be re-used over and over.
You could store a uniquely generated string in a cookie, this string could be used as the primary key.

If you want to store the IP anyway, you could do so along with the token.

```
$myToken = hash('sha256',$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].time());
setcookie('myToken',$myToken,strtotime("+1 month"));
```

But cookies can always be edited, I'd still advise a login.